# Grouping dataframe to get latest message with timestamp sort

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have above dataframe as:

```
    customer_id   message                timestamp        Month
0   9683          txn of INR 234.00      1525266558487      May
1   9683          txn of INR 975.00      1525192344719      May
2   7596          txn of INR 1,363.80    1524905898745    April
3   10661         txn of INR 200.00      1525262750075      May
4   10661         txn of INR 300.00      1524894609266    April
```

I want to `groupby` the dataframe by *customer_id* and *message* and sort by *timestamp* such that I will get latest messages from each month like in `id:9683` and different messages for different months such that we will get latest messages.

The output would look like this

```
customer_id    message                                  month
9683           txn of INR 234.00, txn of INR 975.00       May
7596           txn of INR 1,363.80                      April
10661          txn of INR 200.00                          May
10661          txn of INR 300.00                        April
```

My code is as follows:

```
f = lambda x: x.sort('timestamp', ascending=False)
agg_funcs = {'message':lambda x:','.join(map(str, x))}

df1 = df.groupby(['customer_id','Month']).agg(agg_funcs).apply(f)
```

But I did not get the desired result.

Comment: Can you show us what result you get?

Comment: You are not retrieving the latest *message* but joining all *messages* in customer/Month grouping and you are not grouping by *message* itself.

Comment: I got this result:    message    None dtype: object

Comment: @Parfait i grouped them as                                                                     f = lambda x: x.sort('timestamp', ascending=False)
df.groupby(['customer_id','sender_name','Month']).apply(f)                    but get the result in stacked form i want to be in row by row so that i fetch the first record of that month of correspoding customer_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
df = df.sort_values('timestamp', ascending = False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['customer_id', 'month'], keep = 'first')
df = df.sort_values('customer_id').reset_index()
```

This gives:

```
   customer_id message      timestamp  month
2         7596    msg3  1524905898745  April
0         9683    msg1  1525266558487    May
3        10661    msg4  1525262750075    May
4        10661    msg5  1524894609266  April
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will group by `customer_id` and `Month`, concatenating the `message` fields:

```
df = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'Month'])['message'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

If you want to maintain sorting after the group by, you will need a column in the final dataframe with which to sort, for example, a year column.